# I am running a google script that brings my emails into a spreadsheet, I need assistance troubleshooting a duplication error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been running a script to collect task data for my company, it's been running since 09/03/2023, it seems to have begun duplicating entries at some point and I am struggling to see which tasks are required, or duplication.

This is my script:

```
function getEmails() {
  // Get the first 100 emails in the inbox with the label "HCA"
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Emprevo"', 0, 100);
  
  // Loop through the threads and retrieve the relevant data
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      var subject = message.getSubject();
      var body = message.getPlainBody();
      var emailDate = message.getDate(); // Get the date the email was sent
      
      // Parse the email content to extract the job data
      var jobData = parseEmailBody(emailDate, subject, body);
      
      // Write the job data to the Google Sheet
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
      sheet.appendRow(jobData);
      
      // Mark the email as read and remove the "HCA" label
      message.markRead();
      threads[i].removeLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Emprevo"));
    }
  }
}

function parseEmailBody(emailDate, subject, body) {
  // Parse the email body to extract the relevant data
  // and return it as an array of values
  var senderRegex = /From: (.*?<(.+?)>)/;
  var matches = body.match(senderRegex);
  var sender = matches ? matches[1] : '';
  return [emailDate, subject, sender, body];
}
```

I thought it may be due to thread grouping in Gmail settings, but i have since removed this setting and it still does not work.

The emails are being categorised, and archived as anticipated so I can't see a risk in the trigger pulling in the email twice.

Answer (score 0):

Is there ever a case where there are less than 100 emails with that tag?

If There are only say 80 emails with that thread when it runs then it will only populate the first 80 rows.

If some of those emails were in rows 81-100 the last time the script ran that would leave them there as duplicates.

I’m not sure exactly how to write the code but **make sure you’re clearing out the range where the emails drop every time the script runs** and that might solve it.

Comment: @Alex Stewart was the above suggestion at all helpful?